# @font-face for multiple font-weights doesn't work (SCSS)

Tags: css, sass, font-face

I am trying to define a font-family. I have 18 files, from weight 100 to 900, normal and italic.

My first six definitions work fine. That is: from weight 100 to 300, both normal and italic. From that point on, it just doesn't work.

I have tried using pure CSS. I compiled by hand and the output is correct.

```
// file structure

assets/fonts/
    Poppins-Thin.ttf
    Poppins-ThinItalic.ttf
    Poppins-ExtraLight.ttf
    Poppins-ExtraLightItalic.ttf
    ...
stylesheets/
    _fonts.scss
```

```
// _fonts.scss

@mixin font-face($name, $path, $weight: null, $style: null, $exts: eot woff2 woff ttf svg) {
    $src: null;

    $extmods: (
        eot: "?",
        svg: "#" + str-replace($name, " ", "_")
    );

    $formats: (
        otf: "opentype",
        ttf: "tr@mixin font-face($name, $path, $weight: null, $style: null, $exts: eot woff2 woff ttf svg) {
    $src: null;

    $extmods: (
        eot: "?",
        svg: "#" + str-replace($name, " ", "_")
    );

    $formats: (
        otf: "opentype",
        ttf: "truetype"
    );

    @each $ext in $exts {
        $extmod: if(map-has-key($extmods, $ext), $ext + map-get($extmods, $ext), $ext);
        $format: if(map-has-key($formats, $ext), map-get($formats, $ext), $ext);
        $src: append($src, url(quote($path + "." + $extmod)) format(quote($format)), comma);
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: quote($name);
        font-style: $style;
        font-weight: $weight;
        src: $src;
    }
}

$poppins-weights: ("Thin", "ExtraLight", "Light", "Regular", "Medium", "SemiBold", "Bold", "ExtraBold", "Black");
@for $i from 1 through length($poppins-weights) {
    @include font-face(Poppins, "../assets/fonts/Poppins-#{nth($poppins-weights, $i)}", 100 * $i, normal, ttf);
    @include font-face(Poppins, "../assets/fonts/Poppins-#{nth($poppins-weights, $i)}Italic", 100 * $i, normal, ttf);
}
```